# Что вы понимаете под профессией веб-дизайнер?

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

Лично на мой взгляд - это человек, который создает дизайн-макеты и после их верстает, т.е. умеет рисовать в фотошопе и знает HTML, CSS, JS.

Встречал мнения, что это тот же дизайнер-макетчик, но без знаний HTML, CSS, JS.

Также мне кажется, что если ты верстальщик, то не понимающим людям проще сказать, что ты веб дизайнер, чем рассказать, кто такой и что делает верстальщик...

В общем интересно ваше мнение

---

**Да... В ответах пишут и то и то, что я выше указал...))**

Comment: Сейчас это уже как бы обощающее понятие. К примеру, дизайнер одежды - разрабатывает коллекцию, рисует эскизы, но это не значит, да и не может знаить того, что он не умеет кроить и шить.

P.S. Лично мне не очень нравиться говорить, что я веб-дизайнер людям, далеким от этого направления. Я говорю проще - веб-разработчик. Кстати, обычно слышу в ответ: "А! Так ты компьютерщик. Ну, понятно..." )))

Comment: Че ж вы так не замечаете слово веб и начинаете просто про дизайн))

Comment: @inferus-vv, почему ж не замечаю? Моё первое предложение в комменте - именно к "веб-дизайнеру" и относиться.

Comment: >это человек, который создает дизайн-макеты и после их верстает

это большая редкость люди, которые одинаково хорошо разрабатывают макеты и верстают, к тому же это очень затратно по времени, обычно дизайнер и client side(frontend) developer - 2 разных должности

Comment: @Spectre не представляете, я почему-то в эту группу тоже вхожу :) Зато в последствии верстать легче и быстрее.

Comment: это же хорошо, что на хэшкоде есть такие талантливые люди

Comment: > это человек, создает дизайн-макеты и после их
> верстает

Если и верстает, то это уже работник быдлостудии а не веб-дизайнер!

---------------------------------------

Славьтесь холивары

Comment: @Palmervan почему именно "только работники" могут и рисовать и верстать? Конечно, шаблоны, которые впоследствии пойдут в продакшн, лучше заказывать у дизайнеров, а не у человека "всё в одном", но когда проектик небольшой, либо вы его делаете не спеша, то почему бы не заняться созданием макета, если есть навык?

Comment: @lampa можно конечно, сам рисую) так как за фотошоп еще `CS2` сел 8 лет назад)

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это старый вопрос явно не по теме

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Веб-дизайнер это человек владеющий графическими инструментами (Photoshop, Corel Draw, InDesign...) и умеющий рисовать от руки. Человек творческой натуры. Иногда от него требуют хотя бы приблизительно представлять себе, что такое HTML, CSS, JS. Никакой версткой он не занимается.
От верстальщика требуют поменьше творчества и побольше соответствия верстки дизайну.

Comment: на то оно и web-дизайнер, чтобы мог свой дизайн прикрутить к сайту.

Answer (score 1):

> Дизайн — творческий метод, процесс и
> результат художественно-технического
> проектирования промышленных изделий,
> их комплексов и систем,
> ориентированного на достижение
> наиболее полного соответствия
> создаваемых объектов и среды в целом
> возможностям и потребностям человека,
> как утилитарным, так и эстетическим.

---

> Вёрстка — процесс формирования страниц
> издания путём компоновки текстовых и
> графических элементов.

---

И что именно Вы пытаетесь сравнить?

Comment: Дизайн.. А в вопросе веб дизайн.

Comment: Дизайн - он везде дизайн. На первом месте юзабилити. А если Вы научились юзать фотошоп, и считаете себя дизайнером... Ну что ж, сочувствую.

Comment: Мне сочувствовать не надо. Я умею дизайнерить, но считаю себя верстальщиком. И дизайнерю без всяких фотошопов. На CSS3 минималистические работы

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, какой ответ на свой вопрос Вы хотите услышать? Хотите понять, как представляться людям? Тогда прав @Deonis - "веб-разработчик". Как себя продавать? Тогда, конечно, "дизайнер" - это стоит дороже. "Дизайнер-верстальщик" - если хотите работать на экономных заказчиков. "Верстальщик" - если не хотите брать на себя ответственность за юзабилити. Ну а если Вам нужен термин, который будет определять Ваш внутренний мир описывая Ваши таланты - поищите в себе другие таланты.

Answer (score 1):

Ну ИМХО, веб-дизайнер это человек который умеет нарисовать конфетку, которая очень нравится людям и удобна.

То есть это не только художник и генератор идей, но ещё и человек, который понимает, как должны размещаться элементы на странице, чтоб это соответствовало ожиданиям и посетителя, и заказчика.

А в идеале ещё и имеет представления о верстке, то есть то, что веб-дизайнер рисует не требудет матов и констылей для того, кто будет это преобразовывать из PSD в HTML ))

Насчет именно верстки... на одной конторке, где работал, в штате было много бибизянок, которые с горем пополам умели переколупать страницу и иногда даже наклепать её из картинки с нуля. И была ещё внештатный сотрудник, который за два рисунка зарабатывала больше, чем верстальщики за месяц ((

Comment: Первые два абзаца можно заменить одним словом - юзабилити :)

Comment: Не совсем - юзабилити - это когда кнопка находится именно там, где вы ищите и называется и выглядит так - как привыкли.

"Конфетка" и юзабилити - тяжело совместимые вещи; и чем лучше умеет их совмещать дизайнер - тем дороже он стоит (обратное утверждение не обязательно верное))

Comment: Вроде как вы написали, все таки можно отнести к юзабилити.. "который понимает, как должны размещаться элементы на странице, чтоб это соответствовало ожиданиям и посетителя, и заказчика."

Answer (score 1):

**Профессия web дизайнер**

Web-дизайнер - это разновидность дизайнера. Ему должны быть присуще все классические качества дизайнера, потому, что его задача сделать логичное и приятное глазу оформление информации, которая будет размещена на сайте. Кроме сайтов, веб-дизайнеры разрабатывают баннеры, интернет-открытки, электронные презентации. Одним словом все то, что так или иначе касается графического отображения на страницах Интернета.

**Cпецифика работы web дизайнером:**

*Плюсы профессии:*

- При наличии должного опыта и
  квалификации спрос на рынке труда,
- Не ограничивается пределами одной
  страны,
- Возможность удаленной работы,
- Рынок веб-дизайна дает широкие
  возможности профессионального роста,
- Любая ошибка в дизайне исправима,
- Можно реализовать практически любую
  идею без денежных затрат,
- Достойная оплата труда.

*Минусы профессии:*

- Работать в этой сфере так же тяжело,
  как и в любой другой,
- Сложно сменить столь творческую
  профессию,
- Часто художественное видение
  заказчика и исполнителя не совпадают.
  Из-за чего приходится либо убеждать в
  необходимости конкретного
  дизайнерского решения, либо
  соглашаться с поправками.

**Профильное образование:**

Высшее образование приветствуется, равно как и профильные курсы, но если такового нет обращают внимание на портфолио.
Необходимо знать: Adobe Photoshop.
Желательно знать: Corel Draw, Illustrator, Macromedia Flash, HTML/СSS.